# can not copy in document library with open with explorer sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

we upgraded our SharePoint from 2007 t0 2010 but we have problem while opening  a Document Library with open with browser we can not copy any item in that folder we got the error

> you need permission to perform this action even with SharePoint Admin
>   (spadmin account )

what should we do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you performed an in-place upgrade and that the AD is the same

- Check that your SPAdmin is site collection owner in Central Administration
- Verify that the document library inherit permissions from the site
- Use a 32-bit version of Internet Explorer and verify that the ribbon button "Open with Explorer" is enabled